# jQuery, get width of one element and apply to another

Tags: jquery

Is there a way that I can get the width of one element `.container` for example and apply it to another `.item` for example?

My layout is responsive, hence why I can't just give `.item` a fixed width value.

Comment: Show us some code.  Maybe even a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Does setting width 100% not work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this -

```
$('.item').width($('.container').width());
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/xQ7hh/

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 $('.item').width($('.container').width())
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(".item").width($(".container").width());
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the width without jquery, just simple javascript line of code:

```
var width = document.getElementById('foo').offsetWidth;
```

Note: this will get the width of the element + the border width as well

Ex.
html:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
```

style:

```
.foo {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

in this case the width will be:

```
100px width + 1px right border + 1px left border = 102px
```

Hope that help.